# RxJava Adding Events to Stream based on callback

Tags: java, promise, rx-java, rx-android

Adding some code to clear up the question

```
//generates a sequence in the range from input value (+1) to input value (+9)
Observable<ColoredIntegerModel> getSequenceObservable(int value, int delay, int color) {
        return Observable.range(value+1,9)
                .map(i -> {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Value " + i
                            + " evaluating on " + Thread.currentThread().getName()
                            + " emitting item at " + System.currentTimeMillis());
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(delay);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                    }
                    return new ColoredIntegerModel(i, color);
                });
    }

//creates a stream if say input =2 of numbers from 1-20 (input*2) such that the output is 1 (Red color) 2-10(green color) 11 (Red color) 11-20 (Green Color) 
    Observable<ColoredIntegerModel> getEventStream(int value) {
        return Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<ColoredIntegerModel>() {
            @Override
            public void subscribe(ObservableEmitter<ColoredIntegerModel> emitter) throws Exception {
                for (int i = 0; i < value; ++i) {
                    ColoredIntegerModel model = new ColoredIntegerModel(i*10, Color.RED);
                    emitter.onNext(model);
                    Observable<ColoredIntegerModel> more = getSequenceObservable(i*10, 100, Color.GREEN);
                    more.subscribe(new Consumer<ColoredIntegerModel>() {
                        @Override
                        public void accept(ColoredIntegerModel coloredIntegerModel) throws Exception {
                            emitter.onNext(coloredIntegerModel);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

The code above works. It prints 1(Red) 2-10(Green) 11(Red), 12-20, but I would like a much cleaner solution. I am also not sure when the inner subscription in getEventStream() can be disposed off.

The question basically is that getEventStream is calling a function for each emission that returns an Observable as well. This is analogous to a chain of Promise, in which each individual Promise can return a Series of other Promises. Hope this clarifies any confusion on the original question.

Comment: So, two clarifications required - are you trying to solve a concrete problem (in which case, what is it?), and why are you using nested observables, when you could just use `Observable.fromIterable` or similar?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to resolve concrete internal issue on Android. Our API level requirements API < 17.  The issue is resolved by promises in js implementation. The main issue is that we have series of async promises in then chain, each promise can result in series of promise which need to be resolved before. so if initially we had [promise1, promise2, promise3] and promise1 returned a promise chain [promise1a, promise1b] then order of resolution is [promise1a, promise1b, promise1, promise2, promise3]. I could not find a good promise lib in android to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is simplify the code above so that all subscriptions handling are left to the final subscriber and maintain the order to subsequences emissions, you can do it like this:

```
Observable<ColoredIntegerModel> getSequenceObservable(int value, int delay, int color) {
    return Observable.range(value+1, 9)
            .flatMap( i -> Observable
                    .just(new ColoredIntegerModel(i, color))
                    .delay(delay * (i + 1), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            )
            ;
}

Observable<ColoredIntegerModel> getEventStream(int value) {
    return Observable.range(0, value)
            .concatMap(i ->
                    getSequenceObservable(i * 10,100, Color.GREEN)
                            .startWith(new ColoredIntegerModel(i*10, Color.RED))
            )
            ;
}
```

that is if you really need the manual delay, if you don't, just replace the above `getSequenceObservable` with:

```
Observable<ColoredIntegerModel> getSequenceObservable(int value, int color) {
    return Observable.range(value+1, 9)
            .map(i -> new ColoredIntegerModel(i, color))
            ;
}
```

Comment: sorry above is just an illustration of the real problem. it has nothing to do with delays. the question is if a subscriber is subscribing to sources of events, how can each event handler add things to this sequence.

Comment: I think you need to state better the problem you're trying to solve. a subscriber cannot add events to an upstream observable unless it's a representative of a subject, in that's case you should take a look at subjects http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html.

Comment: Sorry not to be clear, I tried to as clear as I could be. On the questions of subjects also how will you change the events inside it.

Comment: Don't worry. you can check these links, they may give you a sense on subjects. https://medium.com/@bishoy_abd/sending-data-between-different-parts-of-your-app-using-rxjava2-5675153e37c and https://tech.instacart.com/how-to-think-about-subjects-in-rxjava-part-1-ca509b981020

Comment: Thanks for this. I am not sure how subjects resolve the above question as well

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [FlatMap operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html)

In short words it transforms each of the elements in an `Observable` into it's own `Observable` and joins of them.

The simplest solution for your problem could be something like:

```
getEventStream()
    .flatMap(it -> getSequenceObservable(it))
    .doOnNext(System.out::print)
    .blockingSubscribe();
```

Where helper functions are

```
static Observable<ColoredIntegerModel> getEventStream() {
    return Observable.fromArray(
            new ColoredIntegerModel(10, Color.RED),
            new ColoredIntegerModel(20, Color.RED)
    );
}
static Observable<ColoredIntegerModel> getSequenceObservable(ColoredIntegerModel color) {
    return Observable.range(1, 10)
            .flatMap(it -> Observable.timer(it, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .map(time -> new ColoredIntegerModel(time.intValue(), Color.GREEN))
            );
}
```

In case you want to keep original value from `getEventStream()` you can use something like this instead of `getSequenceObservable`

```
static Observable<ColoredIntegerModel> getSequenceObservable(ColoredIntegerModel color) {
     return Observable.range(1, 10)
             .flatMap(it -> Observable.timer(it, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .map(time -> new ColoredIntegerModel(time.intValue(), Color.GREEN)))
             .concatWith(Observable.just(color));
}
```

In case ordering of emissions is important, use flatMap version with maxConcurrency:

```
getEventStream()
            .flatMap(it -> getSequenceObservable(it), true, 1)
            .doOnNext(System.out::println)
            .blockingSubscribe();
```

Comment: That's just an example, you obviously shouldn't call `blockingSubscribe()` on the main thread in production. This would work if you'd call it in on some other thread through.  Another thing missing are calls to `subscribeOn()`.